# Ajax POST, check PHP $_GET and then $_POST

Tags: php, ajax, post, get

Using the following Ajax POST function on form submit (simplified here):

```
    $form.on("submit", function (i) {
          i.preventDefault();
          var sendEmail = 1;
          ValidateForm(sendEmail, "goSignup");
        });
    
        function ValidateForm(sendEmail, action) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: window.location.pathname,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        ajaxRequest: 1,
                        sendEmail: sendEmail,
                    }
}
```

After I post this I want to use a conditional GET parameter that equals 1 (i.e https://www.example.com?test-parameter=1) and then if it's present in the URL use one or another function from there if the ajaxRequest is received from $_POST in my PHP:

```
public function __construct() {
    $testingParameter = $_GET["test-parameter"] ?? '';
    if (trim($testingParameter) == '1') { // if has get parameter equal 
       if (!empty($_POST['ajaxRequest'])) { // if JS postRequest has been posted
                $this->handlePostRequests();
        }
        echo 'has get parameter';
    } else { // else use old logic
        if (!empty($_POST['ajaxRequest'])) {
            $this->handleOtherRequests();
        }
        echo 'no get parameter';
    }
}
```

**Issue:**
I get the correct echo from PHP but when I submit the form with Ajax its still using the `handleOtherRequests();` instead of the `handlePostRequests();` function if I'm using the url [www.example.com?test-parameter=1](http://www.example.com?test-parameter=1).

Likely getting some basic PHP logic wrong here, would appreciate if anyone could guide me in the right direction with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> url: window.location.pathname,
> ```

Your Ajax is never going to POST the data to a URL with a query string because you explicitly took *only* the path name.

Maybe you want `location.href` instead.